# Lighttpd redirect

Tags: httpd.conf, lighttpd

I am re-jigging my website and would like to redirect (not rewrite but not hang up on this) the majority of requests to *.php files to their equivalent *.html files.

I have placed all the files I do not want redirected in one folder aptly named **excluded**, so I can filter the redirect rule on that folder. Here's what I have in my lighttpd.conf file:

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/excluded/" {
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^(.*)\.php(.*)" {
    # this is where I want the redirect rule
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am not sure whether I am missing a $ at the end of the second conditional rule (or whether the ending (.*) is necessary), but I suppose that is where I'd like help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/excluded/" {
  url.redirect = ( "^(.*)\.php(.*)" => "$1.html$2" )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would the default 302 redirect code not be applied to all .php and .html files that don't reside in the excluded with this? That is why I had the second conditional in my code.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  The redirect rule applies only to items it matches.  Your second conditional is redundant if the redirect rule is a single match that is identical to that second conditional.

Comment: very well, I wasn't sure of that thus the basis of my confusion and question.

Comment: a small one, can the conditional have piped orelse's? e.g `$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/excluded/" | $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/otherfolder/" { ... }`

Comment: No, but the url.redirect can contain a list of `url.redirect = ( "match" => "redirect/path", "match2" => "redirect2/path" )`  Please see the documentation: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRedirect

Comment: Reread that.  Your condition can contain '|' in the regex, but not as separate statements, e.g. `$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/excluded/|^/otherfolder/"`  See https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration

Answer (score 0):

OK, the above marked answer did help, however the one that worked, having added another directory to exclude was a little different.

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "/(excluded|otherfolder)/" {
   url.redirect = ( "^(.*)\.php(.*)" => "$1.html$2" )
}
```